# Could not get the message from cloud endpoints starter template to android device

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-cloud-messaging

I'm using google tutorial https://developers.google.com/eclipse/docs/endpoints-androidconnected-gae for google app engine android connect app.
I did everything said in the tutorial, but can't get the message from cloud endpoints starter template, after some time it's giving me error:

java.io.IOException: Could not fetch URL: http android.googleapis.com/gcm/send, error: Received exception executing http method POST against URL https android.googleapis.com/gcm/send: Connection reset

Also searched/viewed all related questions, but I have no idea why it's not working, please help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok I found the solution by myself, I post the answer for someone with the same problem.

The problem was in the QueryMessagesTask in the register activity.The thread starts only one time and that's all. 
After moving QueryMessagesTask to button click listener function everything works. I'm getting the message from the cloud endpoints starter template.